# Packages for Density Estimation using K-Nearest Neighbor

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, k-nn, density-estimation

I would like to have suggestions for packages that provide **K-Nearest Neighbor** *density estimator*, I've already searched the web (*to not bother you guys with my question* :) ), but most results were about kernel density estimator. I know that the both are theoretically related, but I'm looking for something which more specified for **KNN** (*that uses the original formulas of KNN density estimate*).

Note that *R* language packages more preferred, but don't mind *Python*.

Thanks in Advance :D

Answer (score 2):

See this earlier inquiry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840983/knn-density-estimation-r

Also, the [knnde](https://rdrr.io/github/SC19057/package/src/R/knnde.R) function from the SC19057 package is pretty straightforward and is specifically for density estimation. It just requires the R package 'FNN'. You can see the MAN page at https://rdrr.io/github/SC19057/Rpackage/man/knnde.html, and see if it gets you what you need.

For Python, have a look at scikit-learn library. This section of the man pages covers density estimation with sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html